# jQuery remove class from all input, textarea and select elements inside a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery remove the class from all input, text area and select elements inside a specific div

How to remove a class using jQuery from all input, textarea and select elements inside a specific div.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<h4 class="subHead02">Personal Statement
    <span class="action-container">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="edit-link"> 
            <i class="icon-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</h4>
<div class="profile_info_wrap">
    <input type="text" value="test" class="hide"/>
    <textarea class="hide" ros="3" cols="10">I am in text area</textarea>
    <select class="hide">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="hello" class="hide"/>
</div>
```

When to click on edit link (anchor tag with class ="edit-link"), I would like to remove class "hide" from every input, text area and select element inside the div with class "profile_info_wrap".

Tried as follows,

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().next(".profile_info_wrap").find("select,textarea, input").removeClass('hide');
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: __TYPO__ Its `removeClass()` not `remoceClass()`, if _this_ refers to anchor your code should work. Hence closing it

Comment: *"doesn't work"* - any more specifics?  Errors in console (eg "remoceClass not defined" ?

Comment: $(this).parents(".subHead02").siblings(".profile_info_wrap").find("select,input, textarea").removeClass('hide');

Comment: Exactly where are you calling the "tried as follows"?  From a click event on the `i`?

Comment: On a sidenote, why don't you set a `hide` class on `.profile_info_wrap` and hide the elements via css selector? Less clutter in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insead of using parent use closest as

```
$(this).closest('.subHead02').next(".profile_info_wrap").find("select,textarea, input").removeClass('hide');
```

Also correct `remoceClass` to `removeClass`

Also OnClick action of your anchor tag just add `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$(function(){
  
   $('.edit-link').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest('.subHead02').next(".profile_info_wrap").find("select,textarea, input").removeClass('hide');
     
   })

})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="subHead02">Personal Statement
    <span class="action-container">
        <a href="#" class="edit-link"> 
            <i class="icon-edit">hello</i>
        </a>
    </span>
</h4>
<div class="profile_info_wrap">
    <input type="text" value="test" class="hide"/>
    <textarea class="hide" ros="3" cols="10">I am in text area</textarea>
    <select class="hide">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="hello" class="hide"/>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.It works in the snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('.edit-link').click(function(){
      $('.profile_info_wrap').find('.hide').each(function(){
           $(this).removeClass('hide');
      });
 });
```

Hey am posting from phone so there could be some typo.

Thanks

Comment: `$('.profile_info_wrap').find('.hide').removeClass('hide')` will work, no need of `each()`

Answer (score 0):

You have typo mistake removeClass() not remoceClass()

```
jQuery(this).closest('.subHead02').next(".profile_info_wrap").find("select,textarea, input").removeClass('hide');
```